# How can I set first element to display: none;?

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, pseudo-element

So I'm styling this posttype in Wordpress, and when the user links to a soundcloud track that track will show in the post header. Now, if that user posts more than one link I'd like the next ones to be in the content of the post, excluding the first one which already appears in the header.

This is what rougly is output:

```
<div class="content">
    <p><iframe/></p>
    <p><iframe/></p>
    <p><iframe/></p>
    <p><iframe/></p>
</div>
```

How do I style this in CSS so only the last three iframes displays?

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.content:first-child{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked together with iframe at the end, which I found odd, seeing as I thought I had tried it out, so thank you :)